# Use of Google Play Achievement's with Productivity app with game aspects

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-games

I have an app a productivity app [Raise The Bar](http://goo.gl/VoPVA9)  that allows "Users to level up their life". I am trying to incorporate more game aspects into the application, achievements being one of them. Is there any requirements for an app to use Google's game services in particular Achievements. I don't want to implement it just to find out that it doesn't get approved. Any experiences or links to information is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no approval process for using Google Play Games and other examples (such as [Pedometer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.j4velin.pedometer)) which are not 'games' per se that are using Google Play Games Achievements/Leaderboards.

Answer (score 1):

There are several "simple" apps on the play store using the service.

Check out the official google play service [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/games/services/terms).

Section 1 entails the content policies

"Section 1 Developer Content Policies: 
You agree to comply with the Google+ Platform Developer Policies set forth at http://developers.google.com/+/policies and the Google Play content policies set forth at http://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html (or other such URLs as Google may provide for this purpose from time to time).

The content of your API Client, including any content supplied by your users or other content providers, must follow the Google+ User Content and Conduct Policy at http://www.google.com/intl/en/+/policy/content.html. "

You'll realize there's nothing like "Your software application must be a sophisticated video   game with high intensive graphics using OpenGL ES 3.0"